AdMob UMP reports Obtained consent status, but ads fail to load when legitimate interest is disabled. Why?
I’m using AdMob’s User Messaging Platform (UMP) in my Android app to handle user consent for personalized ads. While it generally works as expected, I’ve encountered an issue in a specific scenario:

The user clicks "Manage Options" in the consent dialog instead of "Agree."
In the options menu, they disable legitimate interest for all ad providers and confirm their selection.
The UMP reports the consent status as Obtained (Here I would expect a different value).
When attempting to load personalized ads, nothing happens—no ads are displayed, just the same errors for all ads are shown: ... "Code": 3, "Message": "No fill.", "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads", "Cause": "null", ... .

In all other cases, ads load correctly:

Personalized ads show when the user gives full consent.
Non-personalized ads load when the user declines personalized ads.

It seems like the system is treating this specific scenario incorrectly by reporting Obtained while no valid ad request can be made.
Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to handle it? How can I detect when legitimate interest has been disabled and ensure ads load correctly in this situation?
Thank you for your insights!
